# Possible easier way to split nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays. each nested array contains two members that are comma separated values. What I would like to do is break these nested arrays out into multiple arrays.

So for example, if I have the following array of arrays...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '1,2',
            [c] => 'left, right'
    ],

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '4,5',
            [c] => 'top, middle'
        )
)
```

... I would ultimately like to end up with the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '1',
            [c] => 'left'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '1',
            [c] => 'right'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '2',
            [c] => 'left'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '2',
            [c] => 'right'
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '4',
            [c] => 'top'
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '4',
            [c] => 'bottom'
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '5',
            [c] => 'top'
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'single value',
            [b] => '5',
            [c] => 'bottom'
        )
)
```

I can achieve this with a series of nested foreach loops, but that seems really inefficient - especially considering the fact that some b and c values can contain many elements.

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $a)
{
    foreach(explode(',', $a['b']) as $b)
    {
        foreach(explode(',', $a['c']) as $c)
        {
            $d = [
                'a' => $a['a'],
                'b' => $b,
                   'c' => $c
               ];
               $new_array[] = $d;
           }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to split these out using array functions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this is inefficient? The number of elements you add to your new array is exactly the number of times it must happen... you cannot reduce that. Anyway this question is out of scope for StackOverflow. You could try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but I would consider dropping the question all together.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your solution is OK. In my sample I used recursive function to "hide" one of the nested loops and saved some memory by unseting the processed elements (done by array_shift in the example).

```
function rotate($array, $new_array = array()) {
    $sub_array = array_shift($array);
    $sub_array['b'] = explode(',', $sub_array['b']);
    $sub_array['c'] = explode(',', $sub_array['c']);

    while($b = array_shift($sub_array['b'])) {
    foreach($sub_array['c'] as $c) {
        $new_array[] = array('a' => $sub_array['a'], 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c);
    }
    }
    return $array ? rotate($array, $new_array) : $new_array;
}

$new_array = rotate($array);
```